# How to handle typeorm relations in microservices architecture

Tags: node.js, typescript, microservices, typeorm

If I have two or more nodejs servers connected to the same database (MySQL) as microservices, each one has its own repo with files and an entity folder, how am I supposed to use an entity from a different project (microservice) to create relations between them?

for example, one microservice for users and one for posts.

users microservice entity:

```
@Entity()
class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({unique: true})
    email: string;

    @OneToMany(() => Post, post => post.user)
    posts: Post[];
}
```

posts microservice entity

```
class Post {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column()
    subject: string;

    @Column({type: 'text'})
    body: string

    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.posts)
    user: User;
}
```

Each entity should be able to import the other entity to establish the foreign key relation, however, the entity is in a different project so it cannot be imported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Each microservices MUST BE autonomus. Each Microservices should resolve one and only one step in your entire distributed system. Then, you should research about Event Driven Microservices and Message Queues like Kafka or RabbitMQ approachs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my question isn't about Kafka, RabbitMQ, or any queue solution. Perhaps I was not entirely clear with my question.
I needed a way to describe a foreign key relationship between microservices. Each microservice is autonomous in the sense that it is an isolated NodeJS app that handles its own routes, logic, and data.

The issue is with NodeJS imports. Every microservice has an entity file within its code that describes the relevant table within the database as shown above in my example. But in order to establish a foreign key, one entity must _know_ the other. (import)

Comment: I was able to achieve that by creating a dedicated private repo that holds my entities and can be shared by all of my microservices as a dependency. (using npm install)